# Glide unable to load url images of this type

Tags: android, android-glide

I have used Glide many, many times before, but currently I am having issues to display images with this type of url `https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/nahled/thinking-monkey-11282237747K8xB.jpg`, I don't know why is impossible for me to load it. I even simplified my project to only display this image on MainActivity. When I check the Listener of glide it prompts this error

```
2021-02-19 21:39:43.438 31240-31240/com.y4kuzabanzai.testforvass E/MainActivity: onLoadFailed: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: 503)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

The thing is that I have tried with other Urls and they work just fine. What can be wrong? Here my simple code

MainActivity.class

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.homeImage)


        Glide.with(this)

            .load("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/nahled/thinking-monkey-11282237747K8xB.jpg")
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                Log.e(TAG, "onLoadFailed: ${e}")
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })
            .into(imageView)

    }
```

activity_main.layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 1. <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/homeImage"
               android:layout_width="418dp"
               android:layout_height="492dp"
               android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="109dp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" /> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As it's `status code: 503` error code, I don't think it's related to Glide but the server doesn't respond back.. try to avoid glide and check if you can set it normally.

Comment: I have already tried on the browser and it displays the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it!!!!! The thing is that you have to use a header in such cases where you have to add a User-Agent. Here how I fixed it, note that since I tried several things my code may have changed a bit, thanks Faramarz Afzali for the time. Here my code:

```
private val USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.181 Mobile Safari/537.36"

val glideUrl = GlideUrl(
            gnome.thumbnail,
            LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT).build())

        val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)


        GlideApp.with(itemView.context)
            .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(glideUrl)
            .timeout(60000)
            .override(320, 480)
            .into(binding.gnomeImage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something maybe does not configure properly. Check these out.

- First, you don't need  `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"`
- Second have this inside your  tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```xml
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

- You should know about the size rules of the pictures in glid because there is a problem with loading large images in the glide
- You can try this also put `android:largeHeap="true"` into the tag of the manifest file.

Let me know the result :)

**UPDATE**

If it's not working yet try this.

```java
Glide.with(getContext())
    .asBitMap() //[for new glide versions]
    .load(url)
    //.asBitmap()[for older glide versions]
    //.placeholder(R.drawable.default_placeholder)
    .override(1600, 1600) // Can be 2000, 2000
    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageViewPreview) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap  drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
            super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);   
        }
    });
```

**Or this**

```java
Glide.with('context')
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load('url')
                    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(1600, 1600)) //This is important 
                    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget('imageview') {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            super.onResourceReady(resource, transition);
                             imageview.setImageBitmap(resource);        
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Still not working man, I tried before the  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" approach and  didn't worked, I also added now the android:largeHeap="true" line on manifest and still doesn't work :(

Comment: Please check with Picasso library to see the problem is glide side OR image side

Comment: Just tried Picasso and still the same, I think that this url needs something else, I already used the .override() on Glide too and didn't worked. Thanks for not giving up on me, is well apreciated

Comment: I guess problem is your image size. You can resize image with Picasso like this:
 Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(url)
                .resize(1500, 0)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.download_error)
                .into(imageViewPreview);

Comment: I edited my answer and added UPDATE. Check that.

Comment: Still not working bro, I don't know what is the matter with this urls. Did you tried this url  on a simple project and worked??

Comment: I have tried with .bitmap() in Glide to but is not working :(

Comment: According to the status code: 503, It seems it is the server-side problem. I checked that in the browser and the image loaded. But it's very wired that glide can't load. I hope you will be able to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep trying and I will let you know when I fix it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve this issue, I have been the entire weekend working on it and I haven't found a solution :(

Comment: I suggest opening an issue in the Glide repository in github

Answer (score -2):

正在清单中添加网络安全配置xml文件:

EN: Adding network security configuration xml file to the list:
`res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">developer.alexanderklimov.ru/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

在`AndroidManifest.xml`中添加网络安全配置:

EN: Add network security configuration in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... />
```

[From]https://www.5axxw.com/questions/content/uhfo5y

Comment: Can you write that in English, please?